# How to automatically repeatedly dial a number and automatically press numbers each time?

Tags: calls, automation, phone-app, dialer-codes

I'm trying to get through to the Swedish Migration Agency (Migrationsverket) and their lines are constantly busy. In order to get into the queue, one needs to call them, then press 1 twice. This would be fine, except typically you get a voice telling you that all lines are busy and to call back later. The migration agency then cuts the call. One such cycle takes roughly 30 seconds.

In order to get through, one simply needs to repeat this process repeatedly until there happens to be an available line and one is placed in queue. This can take anything from 5 to 20 minutes of manual calling and pressing depending on chance.

So one needs to call them, wait to be connected, then press 1 twice. Then, when all lines are busy, hang up (or wait for them to cut the call, which takes a few seconds longer), then repeat the process until a line is available and one is placed in queue. I would prefer to spend my time and attention doing something else.

How can I automate this process?

Answer (score 7):

There's an app called [Auto Redial](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=comq.android.autoRedial) that you can configure to keep calling the same number over and over.

I configured it like this:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>(click screenshot to enlarge)</sup>

Note that I added `,1,1` after the number. This makes the phone automatically dial 1 twice, once the call is connected. This works even outside of the app, while dialing a number manually or from the contact list.

I've set the hangup time to maximum because this particular service hangs up automatically when you don't get through. In that case, I can listen to the phone once in a while to check whether I got through yet.

You may need to tweak these settings a bit depending on the service you're calling.

**Disclaimer:** I have no connection to this app whatsoever. The problem described in the question was a real problem I was facing, and when I found the solution I decided to share it with Android Enthusiasts. I have no other motive with this post, and I'm not involved in app development in any way.

Comment: the app does not work!

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Care to clarify? I have used it on several occasions

Comment: I tried this app, however, it requires you to manually hit the hang up button once the busy tone comes through. That is a minor inconvenience. Defeating the purpose of the app, once I received a ring tone, the dialer hung up after a few seconds. The point is to get through to a doctor's office of the unemployment insurance office. Once I get a dial tone, I expect it to ring for a while before it is answered. When the app hung up, I was back at square one. It is useless.

Comment: @Joe Unless the app now has many bugs that it did not have while I was using it, this is not correct. There are settings for how long to wait before hanging up, how many times to automatically redial, etc.

Comment: He's right. You need to hang up and then hit the green dial button again manually. It's possible this won't work for certain phone systems like in North America